# How to go from $H=TS+\mu N$ to $dH=TdS+VdP$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know for a closed system by using Legendre transformation:

$$d[H(S,P,N)]=d(U+PV)=TdS-PdV+PdV+VdP=TdS+VdP$$

But by direct differentiation:

$$d[H(S,P,N)]=d(TS+\mu N)=TdS+\mu dN=TdS$$

The two equations above don't match with each other. And same problem appears when directly differentiating thermal potential $F$ and $G$. So what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function (set $k=1$)

Comment: Why are you not doing $dU=TdS+SdT-PdV-VdP+\mu dN+Nd\mu$?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Because the dependent variables of $U$ is defined (or postulated) to be $\{S,V,N\}$ before the differentiation happened?

Comment: @hyportnex,$$\begin{align}
  H(S,P,N) 
&= TS-μN = (S,P,N)\cdot \nabla H(S,P,N) \\
&= S\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\right)_{P,N} + P\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_{S,N} + N\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial N}\right)_{S,P}\\&=ST+0-Nμ
\end{align}$$ I still can't pull the $VdP$ term out of it though, is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Starting from $H=U+PV$, we have

$$dH=d(U+PV)=dU+PdV+VdP.$$

In conjunction with the [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) $dU=TdS-PdV+\mu dN$, we obtain

$$dH=TdS+VdP+\mu dN.$$

(2) Starting from $H=TS+\mu N$, we have

$$dH=d(TS+\mu N)=TdS+SdT+\mu dN+Nd\mu.$$

In conjunction with the [Gibbs–Duhem relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation) $SdT-VdP+Nd\mu=0$, we obtain

$$dH=TdS+VdP+\mu dN.$$

Same result. (For each, drop the final term for a closed system.)

Answer (score 3):

Since $H = TS+\mu N$, recall that the energy is $E = TS-PV + \mu N$, then $H = E + PV$. If we take the total differential of H we find,
\begin{align}
dH& = dE + PdV + VdP\\
& = TdS - PdV + PdV + VdP\\
& = TdS + VdP,
\end{align}
where we have used $dE = TdS - PdV + \mu dN$ assuming $Nd\mu = 0$ in the second line (which is common).

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am confused about. What happened is when I tried to directly differentiate $H$, so $dH=d(TS+μN)=TdS$ for a closed system, and the $VdP$ term is missing. Why would direct differentiation gives the wrong answer in this case?

Comment: If you go that route, you need to take the total differential of $H$, for what you put this would be $d(TS + \mu N) = TdS + SdT + \mu dN + Nd\mu$. If this is troublesome, recall that really this is a _time dependent_ system, and divide out by a $dt$. But from here, you would have to use the differential for energy, $dE$ to restore the $VdP$ term. The way I did it is just quicker, that's all. But in short, I think you are taking the differential wrongly. To expand a little more, use the product rule on the $TS$ and $\mu N$... (the derivative is a _linear operator_ in a sense).

Comment: I thought $H$ and $U$ are pre-defined as $H(S,P,N)$ and $U(S,V,N)$, thats why I didn't use the product rule. But as you are saying here, if I choose to directly differentiate $dH$, I shouldn't define the independent variable $\{S,P,N\}$ for $H$ at the first place?

Comment: Recall that enthalpy is _defined_ as a function of $H(S,P,N)$, which are the _macrostates_ of the system, and in particular, we took our differentials with respect to a _reversible process_. If you are a little lost, take the simplest system you can think of, say a function $f(x,y)$. I have *no idea* what it is equal to, but I can use some calculus to get: $df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$. And, it may turn out to be, that this is really, $df(x,y) = ydx + xdy$ (you can see where the Maxwell relations come from now too....)